# TFS 2010: Queries based on the elements of other queries?

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

is it possible to create new queries in TFS 2010 based on the result of another query?

For example, one (parent) query selects all work items located under a certain work item (lets say work item with ID=5). And now I want to create other queries, that select all bugs, all tasks etc. from the results of the first query?

There, I only have to change the ID of the "parent" work item once and not in all subsequent queries.

Is this possible in TFS 2010 in combination with VST 2010?

Thanks
Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic support for what you 're after in the GUI editor for WIQL: try with query of type "Tree of Work Items" - which creates a multi-level structure. There is minimal support to what you can handle in this context, for example it's not possible to pick work items with different criterias from level to level.

On the other hand you can implement a custom tool using the TFS-API. There you should be able to tailor to your needs exhaustively. I can support in such endeavor in case you 're interested.

Comment: Ok, I've to admit, that its not possible using normal queries in the current version ... hoping for the new one (2011/2012)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do seems to be more of a report than a plain query. I think you should have a look at implementing custom reports.